# NFC card reader with front facing camera

Tags: android, android-camera, nfc

I am making an application with front facing camera when user going to tap their NFC card it will capture their image. So I made a surfaceview for camera and nfc card reader, added the both 2 functionality in a activity. Both are working separately but when I tap a card surfaceview got frizzed I am not getting any return. Getting error in this line

> NullPointerException

```
 mCamera.takePicture(null, null, ReadCardActivity.this);
```

I have added a button also bellow the surfaceview if I click that image is capturing without any problem.

My code bellow -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read_card);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.preview);
    mPreview.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mPreview.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setNeutralButton("Ok", null).create();

    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mAdapter == null) {
        showMessage(R.string.error, R.string.no_nfc);
        finish();
        return;
    }

    // do we have a camera?
    if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    } else {
        cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
        //cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
        if (cameraId < 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry you don't have secondary camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            releaseCameraAndPreview();
            mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
        }
    }

    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

    mNdefPushMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[]{newTextRecord(
            "Message from NFC Reader :-)", Locale.ENGLISH, true)});
}


private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mCamera.release();
    mAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    Log.d("CAMERA", "Destroy");
}

@OnClick(R.id.buttonCaptureImage)
public void capturingImage() {
    System.gc();
    mPreview.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, ReadCardActivity.this);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You haven't included the code that takes a picture when you tap the NFC card. Are you doing it with a `BroadcastReceiver` inside your activity?

Comment: If you need more information, then update your question

Comment: I solved the problem thanks for all reply I will update the ans.

Comment: ok, if my answer to help solve this Question, please mark it as a accepted, thank you.

Comment: Is this question ready to closed?

Comment: Yes I solved it. I got a good solution over here https://github.com/DanielShum/SimpleCameraView

Answer (score 1):

I think you need your own Callback instead of ReadCardActivity.this

I deal with the same thing for attendance (when the user is accompanied by the tag and then front camera take a picture), so I can give my code ( but in C# Xamarin)

This is the callback class

```
    private class PictureTakenCallback : Java.Lang.Object, Camera.IPictureCallback
{
  private Context parentContext;
  public event PictureTakenEventHandler OnPictureTakenAndReady;
  public PictureTakenCallback()
  {//There have to empty construtor
  }
  public PictureTakenCallback(Context pParentContext)
  {
    this.parentContext = pParentContext;
  }
  public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] pData, Camera pCamera)
  {
    try
    {
      if (OnPictureTakenAndReady != null) OnPictureTakenAndReady(null, new PictureTakenEventArgs(pData));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      string msg = ex.Message;
       ((Activity)parentContext).RunOnUiThread(() => { Toast.MakeText(parentContext, "PictureTakenCallback Exception", ToastLength.Long).Show(); });
    }
  }
}
```

After camera open you create callback

```
          pictureTakenCallback = new PictureTakenCallback(parentContext);
          pictureTakenCallback.OnPictureTakenAndReady += new PictureTakenEventHandler(pictureTakenCallback_OnPictureTakenAndReady);
```

At the moment when you accept the intent from nfcAdapter call this method

```
 public void TakePicture()
    {
      if (cameraFront != null)
      {
        try
        {
          cameraFront.TakePicture(null, null, null, pictureTakenCallback);
          ((Activity)parentContext).RunOnUiThread(() => { Toast.MakeText(parentContext, "After TakePicture", ToastLength.Long).Show(); });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          ((Activity)parentContext).RunOnUiThread(() => { Toast.MakeText(parentContext, "Exception during TakePicture", ToastLength.Long).Show(); }); string msg = ex.Message;
        }
      }
    }
```

If camera take a picture right, then come this event

```
private void pictureTakenCallback_OnPictureTakenAndReady(object sender, PictureTakenEventArgs e)
    {
      if (e.Data != null && e.Data.Length > 0) byte[] photoInBytes = e.Data;
      if (cameraFront != null)
      {
        cameraFront.StartPreview();
        CameraController.IsPreviewStopped = true;
      }
    }
```

Attention, you need StartPreview right and SurfaceView must be visible

Personally, I would recommend everything about of camera put into a separate file / class and make a simple interface than giving it directly to the activity.